# Question regarding a qual problem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to solve this problem appeared in qualifying exam at University of Michigan in 2023.

> **Problem 5:** Let $f(\cdot)$ be an integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $Mf$ the corresponding Hardy-Littlewood maximal function
>
> $$Mf(x) = \sup_{R > 0} \frac{1}{|B(x,R)|} \int_{B(x,R)} |f(y)|\ dy, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^n,$$
>
> where $B(x,R)$ denotes the ball centered at $x$ with radius $R$. Show there is a constant $C_n$, depending only on $n$, such that
>
> $$m \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Mf(x) > s \} \leq \frac{C_n}{s} \int_{\{x : |f(x)| > s/2\}} |f(y)| \ dy.$$
>
> Hint: Consider the function $f_s$ defined by $f_s(x) = |f(x)|$ if $|f(x)| > s/2$, $f_s(x) = 0$ otherwise.
>
> ---
>
> **Solution:** Suppose that $Mf(x) > s$. Then there exists a ball $B(x,R)$ such that
>
> $$\frac{1}{|B(x,R)|} \int_{B(x,R)} |f(y)| \ dy = \frac{1}{|B(x,R)|} \int_{B(x,R)} |f_s(y)|\ dy + \frac{s}{2} > s.$$
>
> We conclude that $\{Mf > s \} \subset \{ M f_s > s/2 \}$. The result now follows from the Hardy-Littlewood inequality applied to $f_s$.

I cant understand how are we getting the Right hand side of the equality in the solution.
I was wondering if someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to mse! I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that other users have an easier time finding this question. In the future, you should do the same ^_^

Comment: I am not sure about how they got the equality specifically, but here is a way to solve the problem without needing it. Note that $$\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|\,dy = \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)} |f_s(y)|\,dy + \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r), |f(y)| \leq s/2} |f(y)|\,dy > s,$$ hence $$\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)} |f_s(y)|\,dy > s - \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r), |f(y)| \leq s/2} |f(y)|\,dy \geq s/2,$$ hence we get $\{Mf > s\} \subset \{Mf_s > s/2\}$ and then the rest of the solution is the same.

Comment: @BBBBBB yeah that's what exactly what have I done, but after seeing their solution I couldn't help but wonder how do they get that $\frac{s}{2}$. Thank you for clarifying!